# SQL - Insert into statement with subquery, then update statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I've been struggling with an SQL statement for a while now, and I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem.

I want to insert a new record in table `A` using a `SELECT` subquery. When this is done, I want to update a record in table `B`.

Here is what I've tried (*dummy SQL, look-alike*):

```
INSERT INTO [A] (ID, Expiration, Type) 
VALUES ({some-id}, (
    SELECT [B].[Expiration], [B].[Type] FROM [B] 
    WHERE [B].ID = {other-id}))
```

When running the statement, I get the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

I'm not quite sure where the error exists, but I suspect that this has something to do with my `where` clause in the `select`

**EDIT**
This query is run from within a .net solution. I have the query setup like this:

```
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO [A] (ID, Expiration, Type) "
    + "VALUES (@someId, (SELECT [B].[Expiration], [B].[Type] "
    + "WHERE [B].ID = @otherId))";

command.CommandText = insertStatement;
command.AddParameter("@someId", someId);
command.AddParameter("@otherId", otherId);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: you can use temp table concept, and then insert temp table to [A].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO [A] (ID, Expiration, Type)
    SELECT {some-id},[B].[Expiration], [B].[Type] FROM [B] 
    WHERE [B].ID = {other-id}
```

Comment: `{some-id}` is not part of the table `[B]`, so wouldn't that just give me another problem?

Comment: Alright this seems to work. Marked as answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Move your `@someId` variable to inside the `Select` query.

Try this

```
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO [A] (ID, Expiration, Type) "
    + "(SELECT @someId, [B].[Expiration], [B].[Type] "
    + "WHERE [B].ID = @otherId)";

command.CommandText = insertStatement;
command.AddParameter("@someId", someId);
command.AddParameter("@otherId", otherId);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Seems to work aswell. Upvoted. Appreciate the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
INSERT INTO A(ID,Expiration,Type)
SELECT @SOME_ID,[B].[Expiration], [B].[Type]
FROM [B]
WHERE [B].ID = {other-id}
```

it should work for you ..